# AutocompleteTextView PopupWindow height

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-popupwindow

I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` at the top of my screen and have used the default List that is associated with the `AutoCompleteTextView` to display my data. I have a bottom navigation bar, at the bottom of my screen, which is visible even when the suggestions are displayed.

The problem I am facing is, when there are too many suggestions in the List of the Popup window, it covers my bottom Navigation bar (List is on top of the bottom Navigation bar). I want to prevent this from happening, by giving a margin to the PopupWindows `ListView` or maybe control the height of the popupWindow. There is an API `setDropdownHeight()` but there is no marginBottom or a way to limit the bottom part of the view from filling the complete screen.

```
/**
 * <p>Sets the current height for the auto-complete drop down list. This can
 * be a fixed height, or {@link ViewGroup.LayoutParams#MATCH_PARENT} to fill
 * the screen, or {@link ViewGroup.LayoutParams#WRAP_CONTENT} to fit the height
 * of the drop down's content.</p>
 *
 * @param height the height to use
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#AutoCompleteTextView_dropDownHeight
 */
public void setDropDownHeight(int height) {
    mPopup.setHeight(height);
}
```

The APIs in `AutoCompleteTextView` gives options to do this for the top/start of this list with APIs like `anchor`, `verticalOffset`, etc. But I have not been able to find an API for doing this at the bottom. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can set this attribute in the description of this widget using the attribute:

```
enter code here

Point pointSize = new Point();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(pointSize);

myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(pointSize.x);
```

try this method

Comment: Where do you want me to add this? Which method will be handling this?